# gem dependency version conflicts between a gem's spec, bundler, and gem install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler, gemspecs

I'm trying to install a gem, meta_search-1.1.0.pre2. The gem's spec, bundler, and rubygems each report/install different dependency version requirements.

I have a new rails3 project ([here are my rails, ruby, rubygems and installed gem versions](http://pastie.org/2564253)), with one new line in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'meta_search', '1.1.0.pre2'
```

[meta_search's page on rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org/gems/meta_search/versions/1.1.0.pre2) reports these dependencies:

```
actionpack ~> 3.1.0.alpha
activerecord ~> 3.1.0.alpha
activesupport ~> 3.1.0.alpha
```

However, installing it pulls down activesupport and activemodel-3.1.1.rc1:

```
 muldoon@fedora14$ gem install meta_search -v 1.1.0.pre2
 Fetching: activesupport-3.1.1.rc1.gem (100%)
 Fetching: meta_search-1.1.0.pre2.gem (100%)

 Fetching: activemodel-3.1.1.rc1.gem (100%)
 Successfully installed activesupport-3.1.1.rc1
 Successfully installed meta_search-1.1.0.pre2
 Successfully installed activemodel-3.1.1.rc1
 3 gems installed
```

..and bundler reports that meta_search needs activesupport-3.1.0.beta1.

```
muldoon@fedora14$ bundle update
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.1.0) depends on
      activesupport (= 3.1.0)

    meta_search (= 1.1.0.pre2) depends on
      activesupport (3.1.0.beta1)
```

Very strange! Any suggestions?

thx!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

When you run `bundle install`, do you get any errors? Bundler should solve any dependency issues for you with this command.

When you run `bundle update`, it searches for the latest version of every gem.

Comment: Answers are not the place to ask for clarification. Please use the question comments for that.

Comment: 'bundle install' reports the same dep issues that 'bundle update' does; in this case, meta_search (= 1.1.0.pre2), as specified in my Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails `3.1.0`, you should be using meta_search `1.1.0`, like this:

```
gem 'meta_search', '1.1.0'
```

Comment: I'm testing another gem that specifies that version of meta_search. This third gem is in beta, and I expect it'll upgrade to the latest version of meta_search before it comes out of beta.

Comment: You're stuck between a rock and a hard place then :-) . I'd use a private copy of the third gem with the dependency replaced in the gemspec, run the third gem tests and go with that if they're all green. Is this an option or it doesn't work if your change the dependency?

Comment: True dat! I'll fork the 3rd gem, upgrade it to the latest meta_search, and see how that goes. thx!!!!